# Skype: Very high ping while using webcam

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, skype, webcam

I recently switched to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. I'm using Skype daily while working. The problem I'm facing is very high ping while my camera's video is open. Normally my ping is around 45ms while Skype call is active, but when I open a webcam it spikes up to 1k ms and stays like that.

Note that the ping while using the webcam on Windows stays at ~50-60 ms. I'm sure that my Internet speed is sufficient for video call.

My cam is: Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000

Skype version: 4.3.0.37.